# Connect to Salesforce from Azure Data Factory configuration

Tags: salesforce, integration, azure-data-factory

as per the documentation at MS, I should be able to configure a custom domain for a salesforce connector through ADF, but i am unable to configure a connection to salesforce.

Doco: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce

i'm unable to change the environment url ...

how would i go about setting a custom url? or do I have permissions related issues for changing this?

Answer (score 0):

ADFv2 visual tool has been updated. You can change the environment url by entering directly in the combo box.

[customize your environment url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bydff.png)